# ggplot2 geom_line() and smoothing

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, linegraph

I am trying to create a GGPLOT2 smoothed line graph that looks more like this

[image]

Source: http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/enso/mei/

and less like this:

[image]

Source: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/Rplot02.png

My data are [available on dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/Data_MEI.csv).

Having looked at previous posts I used the code below:

```
#MEI Line Graph

d4 <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/Data_MEI.csv")
head(d4,n=20)

MEI<-ggplot(d4,aes(x=d4$Date, y=d4$MEI,group=1))+geom_line()

MEI+stat_smooth(method ="auto",level=0.95)
```

What I think I need is to reduce the amount of smoothing taking place, but I have yet to figure out how to achieve this.

```
d4s<-SMA(d4$MEI,n=8)
plot.ts(d4s)
```

SMA() works well but I cant get it to work with ggplot
Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Which graph on that web page are you trying to reproduce?

Comment: apologies...the top one!

Comment: First rule of using statistics codes: if you want to really understand what your analysis and plots show, you have to code things yourself. So, here, I would encourage you to smooth the data external to ggplot so you have more control (and visibility) over whats happening.

Comment: You need to play with moving averages.

Comment: Something like `stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.1)` and adjust the span value to your liking. However, the graph you reference filled the area between line and axis.

Comment: Span! Thats the variable...thank you very much Roland! If you can write this as an answer I will close the question so you get your points, bounty etc!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be aware that the MEI index is for a 2-month period, so it's already got some smoothing built in. Assuming that you are using the MEI data that NOAA ESRL publishes, you should be able to create the same plot.

First of all you need to get the system set up, as you'll be working with timezeones:

```
# set things up  ----
working.dir = file.path('/code/R/StackOverflow/')
setwd(working.dir)
Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')
```

now, download your data and read it in

```
d.in <- read.csv("MEI.txt")
```

The next step is to get the dates formatted properly.

```
d.in$Date <- as.POSIXct(d.in$Date,
                        format = "%d/%m/%Y", 
                        tz = "GMT")
```

and because we need to figure out where things cross the x-axis, we'll have to work in decimal dates. Use the Epoch value:

```
d <- data.frame(x = as.numeric(format(d.in$Date,
                                      '%s')),
                y = d.in$MEI)
```

Now we can figure out the zero-crossings. We'll use [Beroe's example for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959817/filling-area-under-curve-based-on-value-in-ggplot2).

```
rx <- do.call("rbind",
              sapply(1:(nrow(d)-1), function(i){
                f <- lm(x~y, d[i:(i+1),])
                if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(y=0))
                if(d[i,]$x < r & r < d[i+1,]$x)
                  return(data.frame(x=r,y=0))
                else return(NULL)
              }))
```

and tack that on the end of the initial data:

```
d2 <- rbind(d,rx)
```

now convert back to dates:

```
d2$date <- as.POSIXct(d2$x,
                      origin = "1960-01-01",
                      format = "%s",
                      tz = "GMT")
```

now we can do the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d2,aes(x = date,
              y = y)) + 
  geom_area(data=subset(d2, y<=0), fill="blue") + 
  geom_area(data=subset(d2, y>=0), fill="red") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "MEI")
```

and that gives you this:

[image]

Now, do you really need to smooth this?

Comment: Why do you use `POSIXct` for this? `Date` should be preferable as you wouldn't have to worry about time zones.

Comment: I use posixct precisely because it lets me control time zones. I do a lot of work with time series data and I prefer to be able to control exactly what happens to any date/time. Also, I did need to calculate the zero crossings so I figured posixct as I could convert those times into epoch seconds and get the zero crossings more accurately.

Comment: I should add that as soon as you start changing date / time formats then time zones can bite.

Comment: Im not sure if anyone will pick this up, but I have come back to this example and data.frame(x = as.numeric(format(d$Date,'%s')),y = d$MEI) is turning my Dates into NA's, any idea why this might be? Would reading if from a CSV rather than a text file make a difference?

Comment: @Methexis: it's hard to say without a worked example that explains your question about read.csv in more depth. I suspect your problem is actually with the date formatting in your comment, not the read. I'd look at the first row in 'd' to confirm the read from file worked, then debug from there.

Comment: odd....started a fresh session of RStudio this morning and all was good! Thanks again!

Comment: @Methexis; could you provide some feedback on my answer to your original question? I'm happy to try to expand if required. Otherwise if it's a good answer there's always the big green tick thing you could click on :)