# R ggplot2: overlaying multiple geom_ribbon objects in a single plot using a nested loop

Tags: r, nested, ggplot2

I have five line plots from which I'd like to output a shaded area that represents the region between their plotted upper and lower regions. I'm creating an R script (see below) as I have multiple datasets for which I need to repeat this exercise.

However, I'm only able to print the geom_ribbon from the last i and j pair -  I can't seem to output every geom_ribbon into the created list.

I'd grateful for any ideas on how to import all of the geom_ribbon objects into the list. Only one plot is printed with `print(Z)`(example below). I'd like, if possible, all geom_ribbon objects to be overlain and printed as a single ggplot?

```
Z <- list()
allmaxi <- list(cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxa, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxc,cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxd, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxe, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxf)
allmaxj <- list(cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxa, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxc,cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxd, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxe, cahp_max_plot15cb$decade_maxf)
for (i in allmaxi) {
  for (j in allmaxj) {
    l <-  geom_ribbon(data=cahp_max_plot15cb,aes(x=decade,ymin=i, ymax=j))
    Z[[length(Z) + 1]] <- l
    print(i)
    print(j)
  }     
}
print(ggplot() + Z)
```

Sample output (from print(i) and print(j) in script) from inputting one dataset (decade_maxa) to i list, and four other data sets to j list:

```
[1] 2010.811 1723.783 1961.088 1662.909 1587.191 1662.140 1665.415 1602.974 1807.453 1586.106 
[11] 1580.880 1685.253 1653.178 1824.842

[1] 1390.260 1247.700 1263.578 1711.638 1228.326 1762.045 1260.147 1171.914 1697.987 1350.867
[11] 1434.525 1488.818 1610.513 1536.895
`
 `[1] 2010.811 1723.783 1961.088 1662.909 1587.191 1662.140 1665.415 1602.974 1807.453 1586.106
[11] 1580.880 1685.253 1653.178 1824.842
`
 `[1] 1120.2700 1094.3047 1196.8792 1227.9660 1236.9170 1266.0935 1127.1480  974.6948  947.3365
[10] 1244.3242 1254.2704 1082.3667 1286.9080 1126.1943
`
 `[1] 2010.811 1723.783 1961.088 1662.909 1587.191 1662.140 1665.415 1602.974 1807.453 1586.106
[11] 1580.880 1685.253 1653.178 1824.842
`
 `[1] 1396.695 1425.073 1382.941 1913.495 1401.754 1499.763 1600.656 1367.043 1413.390 1343.804
[11] 1431.790 1402.292 1329.192 1696.729
`
 `[1] 2010.811 1723.783 1961.088 1662.909 1587.191 1662.140 1665.415 1602.974 1807.453 1586.106
[11] 1580.880 1685.253 1653.178 1824.842
`
 `[1] 1718.874 1389.134 1501.574 1233.189 1262.480 1508.919 1291.467 1431.869 1505.102 1376.519
[11] 1441.181 1421.552 1326.547 1635.599
`
> print(ggplot() + Z)

`
```

This is my aim. Maybe there is a better way with lapply?

[image: insert]

This is the image output by integrating median values, as proposed below:

`median_g <- group_by(cahp_max_plot15cbm,decade)
median_gm <- mutate(median_g, median=median(value))
p2 <- ggplot(median_gm) + geom_ribbon(aes(x=decade, ymin=median,ymax=value,group=variable),alpha=0.40,fill="#3985ff") +
  geom_line(aes(x=decade,y=value,group=variable,color=variable),lwd=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=decade,y=median))
p2`

[image]

Comment: It appears the variable names (only i and j) are not being passed to the list:> Z
[[1]]
mapping: x = decade, ymin = i, ymax = j 
geom_ribbon: na.rm = FALSE 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

[[2]]
mapping: x = decade, ymin = i, ymax = j 
geom_ribbon: na.rm = FALSE 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

[[3]]
mapping: x = decade, ymin = i, ymax = j 
geom_ribbon: na.rm = FALSE 
stat_identity:  
position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

 ...

Comment: Why do you need this in a loop? Better approach is probably to reshape your data. More readable, and easier plot customization.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly over-engineered solution: find all segment-segment intersections, add those abscissae to the mix, and for each x locate the min and max values.

```
# some segment-segment intersection code
# http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
ssi <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4){

  denom <- ((y4 - y3)*(x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3)*(y2 - y1))
  denom[abs(denom) < 1e-10] <- NA # parallel lines

  ua <- ((x4 - x3)*(y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3)*(x1 - x3)) / denom
  ub <- ((x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x1 - x3)) / denom

  x <- x1 + ua * (x2 - x1)
  y <- y1 + ua * (y2 - y1)
  inside <- (ua >= 0) & (ua <= 1) & (ub >= 0) & (ub <= 1)
  data.frame(x = ifelse(inside, x, NA), 
             y = ifelse(inside, y, NA))

}
# do it with two polylines (xy dataframes)
ssi_polyline <- function(l1, l2){
  n1 <- nrow(l1)
  n2 <- nrow(l2)
  stopifnot(n1==n2)
  x1 <- l1[-n1,1] ; y1 <- l1[-n1,2] 
  x2 <- l1[-1L,1] ; y2 <- l1[-1L,2] 
  x3 <- l2[-n2,1] ; y3 <- l2[-n2,2] 
  x4 <- l2[-1L,1] ; y4 <- l2[-1L,2] 
  ssi(x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4)
}
# testing the above
d1 <- cbind(seq(1, 10), rnorm(10))
d2 <- cbind(seq(1, 10), rnorm(10))
plot(rbind(d1, d2), t="n")
lines(d1)
lines(d2, col=2)
points(ssi_polyline(d1, d2))

# do it with all columns of a matrix (common xs assumed)
# the general case (different xs) could be treated similarly
# e.g by doing first a linear interpolation at all unique xs
ssi_matrix <- function(x, m){
  # pairwise combinations
  cn <- combn(ncol(m), 2)
  test_pair <- function(i){
    l1 <- cbind(x, m[,cn[1,i]])
    l2 <- cbind(x, m[,cn[2,i]])
    pts <- ssi_polyline(l1, l2)
    pts[complete.cases(pts),]
  }
  ints <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(cn)), test_pair)
  do.call(rbind, ints)

}
# testing this on a matrix
m <- replicate(5, rnorm(10))
x <- seq_len(nrow(m))
matplot(x, m, t="l", lty=1)
test <- ssi_matrix(x, m)
points(test)

# now, apply this to the dataset at hand

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(decade=1:10)
n=nrow(data)
data$maxa <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxb <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxc <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxd <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxe <- runif(n,1000,2000)

newpoints <- setNames(data.frame(ssi_matrix(data$decade, data[,-1L]), 
                                 "added"), c("decade", "value", "variable"))
mdata <- melt(data, id=1L)

interpolated <- ddply(mdata, "variable", function(d){
  xy <- approx(d$decade, d$value, xout=newpoints[,1])
  data.frame(decade = xy$x, value=xy$y, variable = "interpolated")
})

all <- rbind(mdata, interpolated, newpoints)

rib <- ddply(all, "decade", summarise, 
             ymin=min(value), ymax=max(value))

ggplot(mdata, aes(decade)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = rib, aes(x=decade, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),
              alpha=0.40,fill="#3985ff")+
  geom_line(aes(y=value, colour=variable))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by the question, and wanted to see if I could get to an answer with simulated (but similar) data as I like making plots. I included my first approach which didn't work completely as intended, for illustrative purposes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(decade=1:10)
n=nrow(data)
data$maxa <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxb <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxc <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxd <- runif(n,1000,2000)
data$maxe <- runif(n,1000,2000)
```

First approach: calculate min and max, and use those to calculate a ribbon

```
data$min <- apply(data[,-1],MARGIN=1,FUN=min)
data$max <- apply(data[,-1],MARGIN=1,FUN=max)

#reshape
data_long <- melt(data, id.vars=c("decade","min","max"))

#plot
p1 <- ggplot(data_long) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=decade,ymin=min,ymax=max),fill="#FFCCCC", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=decade,y=value,group=variable,col=variable),size=1) 

p1
```

[image]
does not get intended result; plots ribbons between peaks.

Second approach; should work for data dat are not too extreme: find median value for each decade, and use that as ymin for the ribbon. ymax is the value in the melted dataset.

```
#find median 
data_long <- ddply(data_long,.(decade),transform, median=median(value))

#plot. Quick hex-color and no alpha because the ribbons overlap, and that becomes visible with alpha.
p2 <- ggplot(data_long) + geom_ribbon(aes(x=decade, ymin=median,ymax=value,group=variable),fill="#FFCCCC")+
  geom_line(aes(x=decade,y=value,group=variable,col=variable),size=1) 

p2
```

[image]

Works!

Comment: This is a really nice concise approach!

I applied to my data, as in the image above*

However, I noticed that if an alpha value is included (which is additional to my original question) to display overlaps, then there appear to be some shading artefacts close to the median values (median points are plotted in image above). I'll explore further to see if these can be eliminated.

*image: I inserted image in my original question as it seems I'm unable to post an image here  in a comment.

Comment: also had the issue with alpha and overlaps (which is quite expected if you think about it, so I chose a similar color but kept alpha at 1. You can use a color website/tool to find the code for the fill colour you desire.