# Color variation with geom_polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a plot where the area between to lines is filled based on a factor of a variable. I want the polygon to be red when line `ya > yb` and green when `yb > ya`.

```
xa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ya <- c(1,10,15,7,12,3)
xb <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
yb <- c(5,10,14,12,2,11)
toyset <- as.data.frame(cbind(xa, ya, xb, yb))
toyset$color<-ifelse(toyset$yb>ya,"green","red")

poly_df <- rbind(setNames(toyset[,c(1,2,5)],c('x','y','color')),
             setNames(toyset[6:1,3:5],c('x','y','color')))
```

This is not working at all:

```
ggplot(toyset) + 
 geom_line(aes(xa, ya), colour="red") + 
 geom_line(aes(xb, yb), colour="green") +
 geom_polygon(data = poly_df,aes(x = x,y = y,fill=poly_df$color))
```

Here the polygons are okay, but there are no different colors (see image):

```
ggplot(toyset) + 
 geom_line(aes(xa, ya), colour="red") + 
 geom_line(aes(xb, yb), colour="green") +
 geom_polygon(data = poly_df,aes(x = x,y = y),fill=poly_df$color)
```

[image: plot with no colour variation]

Comment: I guess you need to define the coordinates of each of the five polygons first and assign an id and colour to each polygon, then you can use `geom_polygon(data = poly_df, aes(x = x,y = y, fill = id, colour = id))`

Comment: Didn't I do that already by creating poly_df?

Comment: I don't think so. You also need to include those points where both lines intersect.

Comment: So only the points where they intersect and delete the other points? Because the points where they intersect are already in there.

Comment: No, they are not, you need those to complete poly_df. If I am not mistaken you are looking for five polygons, where each needs 3 (first and last) or 4 (polygon 2,3 and 4) sets of x and y coordinates. E.g. the second one already has coordinates (x=2, y=10), (x=3, y=15) and (x=3, y=14) but lacks the coordinates for where the both lines intersect, somehwere around (x=3.2, y=13.8).

Comment: That is a lot of work if to this for a lot of polygons. You now of an other method that can do what I want, but is less of hassle?

Comment: maybe this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32284831/471093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example in this [blog](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/ggplot2-two-color-xy-area-combo-chart/) you could proceed as follows.

We use the initial toy data-set (slightly adjusted)

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y1 <- c(1, 10, 15, 7, 12, 3)
y2 <- c(5, 10, 14, 12, 2, 11)
toyset <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, y1, y2))
```

In order to change the fill colour at each point where two lines cross, we calculate the points of intersection.

```
toyset$slope1 <- c(NA, with(toyset, diff(y1)/diff(x1)))
toyset$slope2 <- c(NA, with(toyset, diff(y2)/diff(x1)))
toyset$intcpt1 <- with(toyset, y1 - slope1 * x1)
toyset$intcpt2 <- with(toyset, y2 - slope2 * x1)
toyset$x2 <- with(toyset, (intcpt1 - intcpt2)/(slope2 - slope1))
toyset$y3 <- with(toyset, slope1 * x2 + intcpt1)
toyset <- toyset[, c(-4:-7)]
```

To make sure that calculations are correct, we can visually check the location of the points of intersection:

```
ggplot(toyset) + geom_line(aes(x1, y1), colour = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x1, y2), colour = "darkgreen") +
  geom_point(aes(x2, y3), colour = "darkblue", size = 3)
```

As we will be using `geom_ribbon`, the points of intersection need also to be presented in the form expected by `geom_ribbon(x, ymin, ymax)` – a simple copy of `y3` accomplishes this.

```
toyset$y4 <- toyset$y3
```

We perform additional error checking and assign each data point to the appropriate interval.

```
toyset[which(toyset$x2 > toyset$x1), c("x2", "y3", "y4")] <- NA
toyset$segment <- findInterval(toyset$x1, 
                               c(min(toyset$x2, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                     toyset$x2[which(!is.na(toyset$x2))]))
```

For `ggplot2` to be able to vary the fill colour at each crossing of the lines, it needs to know the start and end point of each coloured area. This means that the middle points of intersection need to be duplicated, as they would be part of two adjacent areas filled with different colours.

```
toyset$x3 <- c(tail(toyset$x2, -1), NA)
toyset$y5 <- c(tail(toyset$y3, -1), NA)
toyset$y6 <- toyset$y5
```

Now the coordinates of two lines and the start/end points of coloured areas need to be combined into one data.frame in a long format.

```
toyset1 <- toyset[, c(1:3, 7)]
toyset2 <- toyset[!is.na(toyset$x2), c(4:6, 7)]
toyset3 <- toyset[!is.na(toyset$x3), c(8:10, 7)]

names(toyset2) <- names(toyset1)
names(toyset3) <- names(toyset1)

combo <- rbind(toyset1, toyset2)
combo <- rbind(combo, toyset3)
combo <- combo[is.finite(combo$y1), ]
combo <- combo[order(combo$x1), ]
```

We can now fill the segments accordingly.

```
ggplot(combo, aes(x1, ymin = y1, ymax = y2))+ 
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = factor(segment%%2)), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_path(aes(y = y1), colour = "red", size = 1) + 
  geom_path(aes(y = y2), colour = "darkgreen", size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green"))
```

[Segments filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUmRK.png)

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to work! Thanks! If you post the full answer here as well I can mark it as answered. Just linking the blog may result in losing the information over time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow. Not sure if there is a simpler approach to this problem, but i hope my full answer helps!