# R: How plot negative and positive anomaly (for this data) with ggplot?

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have this `df`

```
               x          acc
1  1902-01-01  0.782887804
2  1903-01-01 -0.003144199
3  1904-01-01  0.100006276
4  1905-01-01  0.326173392
5  1906-01-01  1.285114692
6  1907-01-01  2.844399973
7  1920-01-01 -0.300232190
8  1921-01-01  1.464389342
9  1922-01-01  0.142638653
10 1923-01-01 -0.020162385
11 1924-01-01  0.361928571
12 1925-01-01  0.616325588
13 1926-01-01 -0.108206003
14 1927-01-01 -0.318441954
15 1928-01-01 -0.267884586
16 1929-01-01 -0.022473777
17 1930-01-01 -0.294452983
18 1931-01-01 -0.654927109
19 1932-01-01 -0.263508341
20 1933-01-01  0.622530992
21 1934-01-01  1.009666043
22 1935-01-01  0.675484421
23 1936-01-01  1.209162008
24 1937-01-01  1.655280986
25 1948-01-01  2.080021785
26 1949-01-01  0.854572563
27 1950-01-01  0.997540963
28 1951-01-01  1.000244163
29 1952-01-01  0.958322941
30 1953-01-01  0.816259474
31 1954-01-01  0.814488644
32 1955-01-01  1.233694537
33 1958-01-01  0.460120970
34 1959-01-01  0.344201474
35 1960-01-01  1.601430139
36 1961-01-01  0.387850967
37 1962-01-01 -0.385954401
38 1963-01-01  0.699355708
39 1964-01-01  0.084519926
40 1965-01-01  0.708964572
41 1966-01-01  1.456280443
42 1967-01-01  1.479412638
43 1968-01-01  1.199000726
44 1969-01-01  0.282942042
45 1970-01-01 -0.181724504
46 1971-01-01  0.012170186
47 1972-01-01 -0.095891043
48 1973-01-01 -0.075384446
49 1974-01-01 -0.156668145
50 1975-01-01 -0.303023258
51 1976-01-01 -0.516027310
52 1977-01-01 -0.826791524
53 1980-01-01 -0.947112221
54 1981-01-01 -1.634878300
55 1982-01-01 -1.955298323
56 1987-01-01 -1.854447550
57 1988-01-01 -1.458955443
58 1989-01-01 -1.256102245
59 1990-01-01 -0.864108585
60 1991-01-01 -1.293373024
61 1992-01-01 -1.049530431
62 1993-01-01 -1.002526230
63 1994-01-01 -0.868783614
64 1995-01-01 -1.081858981
65 1996-01-01 -1.302103374
66 1997-01-01 -1.288048194
67 1998-01-01 -1.455750340
68 1999-01-01 -1.015467069
69 2000-01-01 -0.682789640
70 2001-01-01 -0.811058004
71 2002-01-01 -0.972374057
72 2003-01-01 -0.536505225
73 2004-01-01 -0.518686263
74 2005-01-01 -0.976298621
75 2006-01-01 -0.946429713
```

I would like plot the data in this kind:
[image]

where on x axes there is column x of `df`, and on y axes column `acc`.
Is possible plot it with ggplot?
I tried with this code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=acc))+
geom_linerange(data =df , aes(colour = ifelse(acc <0, "blue", "red")),ymin=min(df),ymax=max(cdf))
```

but the result is this:
[image]

Please, how I can do it?

Comment: This post gives the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959817/filling-area-under-curve-based-on-value-in-ggplot2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I'm not sure.

```
ggplot(data = df,mapping = aes(x,acc))+geom_segment(data = df , mapping = aes(x=x,y=ystart,xend=x,yend=acc,color=col))
```

[image]

```
df$x=year(as.Date(df$x))
df$ystart=0
df$col=ifelse(df$acc>=0,"blue","red")
```

[image]