# geom_area different fill colour when above critical level

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a geom_area to have twin colours dependant on value of Y axis.

So for example if we have a geom_area with a max X value of 50, I would like the fill colour to be blue when below 10 and red when above 10.

Sample Data;

```
df <- data.frame(
  y = sample(1:50),
  x = sample(1:50)
)
```

The closest that I have managed to get thus far is by using the following code;

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y = y),fill = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(y >= 10,10,y)),fill = "blue")
```

This almost gets me what I require however the problem is that the horizontal split is not completely across the geom_area, as when the next value falls below the max value the edge of the ribbon goes straight to the next point, which upsets the split.

[image: SamplePlot]

This is plotting exactly what the code tells it, so I must be using the wrong method to create the split in colours, but cannot figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959817/filling-area-under-curve-based-on-value-in-ggplot2) might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

A quick fix would be to interpolate between the x-values using `approx`. Set the `n` argument (the number of interpolation points) to a high-enough value to get blue all the way across:

```
ggplot(data = as.data.frame(approx(df,n=1000)), aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_area(aes(y = y),fill = "red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ifelse(y >= 10,10,y)),fill = "blue") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually quite close to what I need however, I think I may have a better idea.I should be able to subset the observations to where the Y value crosses the horizontal level. Once I have two points I can then calculate the slope and the intercept. Then I can use the intercept values on geom_ribbon to have the correct fill. Not entirely sure of a good way to go about this or if it will work so any suggestions will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The linked answer in @aosmith's comment has code for doing that.