# How to plot a continuous line with repeating x-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data set of Standardized Precipitation Index values from 1980 to 2005. There is one value for each month, so altogether there are 312 (26 years * 12 months) values. The SPI values range between -3 and +3. Here is an easy reproducible example, since the exact values are not important for my question:

```
vec1 <- rep(seq(1980, 2005), each= 12)
vec2 <- sample(x = -3:3, size = 312, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
colnames(df) <- c("Year", "SPI")
```

Now I would like to plot the SPI values with the years being the x-axis.

When I try to plot it using ggplot2:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=df$Year, y=df$SPI))
```

Something like this comes out:
[image]

So the problem is, there is no continuous line.

I can plot it with a continuous line with Base R for example:

```
plot(vec2, type="l")
```

But then the problem is that the x-axis only shows the values 1:312 and I need the years as the x-values.

Anybody with a hint?

EDIT after the answer of marcguery:

It turned out that I cannot use a line plot for my purpose. Instead, I need to do a column plot with many single columns when using ggplot2 since I need to color the areas above/below zero.

marcguery's answer works for a `geom_line()` plot, but unfortunately not for a `geom_col()` plot. I have no idea why.

Here is the modified code:

```
vec1 <- seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), 
            by = "month", 
            to = as.Date("2005-12-01"))
vec2 <- sample(x = -3:3, size = 312, replace = TRUE)
vec3 <- 1:312
df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2, vec3)
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "SPI", "ID")


library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

This is what unfortunately does not work with the dates as x-axis, there is a strange output:

```
library(ggplot2)
# with Date as x-axis
ggplot(data= df, aes(x= Date, y= SPI, width= 1)) +
  geom_col(data = df[SPI <= 0], fill = "red") +
  geom_col(data = df[SPI >= 0], fill = "blue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

This is what works with the simple rownumber as x-axis:

```
# with ID as x-axis 
ggplot(data= df, aes(x= ID, y= SPI, width= 1)) +
  geom_col(data = df[SPI <= 0], fill = "red") +
  geom_col(data = df[SPI >= 0], fill = "blue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I need something like the last example, just with the dates as the x-axis.

Comment: What is the plot you posted showing? Is it one observation for each year? It doesn't look like they're plotting all 12 for each year to me, but I might be wrong

Comment: @Matt Kaye: Yes, normally there is a value for every single month of each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations per month of each year have all the same value in your column `Year`, hence why `ggplot` cannot assign them different x values. Since you are working with dates, you could use `Date` format for your time points so that each month is assigned a different value.

```
#Seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
#Data
vec1 <- seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), 
            by = "month", 
            to = as.Date("2005-12-01"))
vec2 <- sample(x = -3:3, size = 312, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "SPI")

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = SPI))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y",
               limits = c(as.Date("1979-12-01"),
                          as.Date("2006-01-01")),
               expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

**Edit after you added your question about coloring the area between your values and 0 based on the sign of the values:**

You can definitely use a `geom_line` plot for that purpose. Using a `geom_col` plot is a possibility but you would loose visual information about change between your x variables which are continuously related as they represent dates.

To plot a nice `geom_line`, I will base my approach on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009173/14027775. You will have to adapt your data by transforming your dates to numerical values, for instance number of days since a given date (typically 1970/01/01).

```
#Colored plot
#Numerical format for dates (number of days after 1970-01-01)
df$numericDate <- difftime(df$Date,
                           as.Date("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                           units="days")
df$numericDate <- as.numeric(df$Date)

rx <- do.call("rbind",
              sapply(1:(nrow(df)-1), function(i){
                f <- lm(numericDate~SPI, df[i:(i+1),])
                if (f$qr$rank < 2) return(NULL)
                r <- predict(f, newdata=data.frame(SPI=0))
                if(df[i,]$numericDate < r & r < df[i+1,]$numericDate)
                  return(data.frame(numericDate=r,SPI=0))
                else return(NULL)
              }))
#Get back to Date format
rx$Date <- as.Date(rx$numericDate, origin = "1970-01-01")

d2 <- rbind(df,rx)

ggplot(d2,aes(Date,SPI)) + 
  geom_area(data=subset(d2, SPI<=0), fill="red") +
  geom_area(data=subset(d2, SPI>=0), fill="blue") + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y",
               limits = c(as.Date("1979-12-01"),
                          as.Date("2006-01-01")),
               expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Now if you want to keep using `geom_col`, the reason why you don't see all the bars using dates for the x axis is that they are too thin to be filled as they represent one single day over a long period of time. By filling and coloring them, you should be able to see all of them.

```
ggplot(data= df, aes(x= Date, y= SPI)) +
  geom_col(data = df[df$SPI <= 0,], 
           fill = "red", color="red", width= 1) +
  geom_col(data = df[df$SPI >= 0,], 
           fill = "blue", color="blue", width= 1) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y",
               limits = c(as.Date("1979-12-01"),
                          as.Date("2006-01-01")),
               expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: @ marcguery: thanks a lot for the answer, it is already very helpful. But I found myself facing another problem now. Your answer works great for a geom_line plot. I need to do a geom_col plot and then it starts getting tricky, I really have no idea why. I will make an EDIT above so you can see what I mean. Hope you have a hint for that, too.

Comment: @climdrag kindly ask one question at a time. (please ask a new question). Please don't forget to reference this first question when asking the new question. And please kindly consider accepting this answer here if it has resolved your (first) question

Comment: @ marcguery: thank you so much for your help, now it is exactly what I wanted.
@ tjebo: sorry for the confusion